# variables with relationships change during return

Tags: php, laravel, return

I use Laravel.
I have relationship between post and comments. 
I have `$post` and I'd like to get related `$comments` only with value `published` set to `true`.
In controller I have:

```
$post     = Post::find($id);
$comments = $post->comments->where('published', 1)->get();
```

And here variable `comments` looks properly, but when I do:

```
return [
    'comments' => $comments,
    'post'     => $post,
];
```

I have all comments from db and post connecting with comments in one array.
e.g

```
$post: 
id  24
title   "lorem"
body  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis explicabo molestias obcaecati placeat vero. Alias aliquid consectetur, deserunt ducimus iure magnam minus molestias neque pariatur quidem sint temporibus totam vitae."
user_id 2
published   1
created_at  "2018-12-03 12:14:30"
updated_at  "2019-03-29 10:08:26"
comments    [
    1 [ ... ]
    2 [ ... ]
    n [ ... ] 
]

$comments {
 1 [ ... ]
 2 [ ... ]
 n [ ... ] 
}
```

So where did I make a mistake? Why does it change?

model Comment.php

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function scopePublished($query)
{
    return $query->where('published', 1);
}
```

Post.php

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `eager-loading` ?  you can check my post

Comment: Before I get comments I already have post. I showed a simplified version of me logic :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$post     = Post::with(['comments' => function($q) {
                     $q->where('published', 1); // or $q->published();
                 }])
                ->find($id);
```

You can read [Where with relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

In blade file, you can get post and comments using

```
{{ dd($post) }} //get post
{{ dd($post->comments) }} //get post related commnets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$comments = $post->comments->where('published', 1)->get();
```

checks for **posts** that have published set as 1. 
To get published comments for any post, add a new relationship in your Post.php as follows :

```
public function publishedComments()
{
    return $this->comments()->where('published', 1);
}
```

You can then use it in your controller like so

```
$comments = $post->publishedComments()->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! That works! I shouldn't use my ```scopePublished``` method in Comment.php

Comment: That should work too. Just use it instead of `where('published', 1)` in `publishedComments()`